# HTML text-field value with 'special characters'

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

Probably this is a known problem and there is a specific best practice.

I have to fill a text field value with received text from backend.

I this text contains some 'special characters' (for example " <) I have some issued during the rendering of the page.

How can I solve this?

Can I solve this issue front-end side?
**I can use only javascript front-end side. I not use PHP;**

I use this html code:

```
<input class="myclass" value="<%= text_from-backend %>" placeholder="My Placeholder"/>
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you specify what the "some issues" are that you have and what templating system that is. A [mcve] please.

Comment: probably what you are looking for are html entities like `&gt;` which, if you put it into your html, will be rendered as `>`, but the question is not specific indeed

Answer (score -3):

You can replace special characters in PHP:

```
<input class="myclass" value="preg_replace('/[^ a-z\d]/ui','','<%= text_from-backend %>');" placeholder="My Placeholder"/>
```